# I want to apply the count animation individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want the number count animation effect to be applied as the text is.
However, when there are two or more numB classes, the combined value is displayed.
I want to give each tag the same effect.

```
<div class="numB">12345</div>
<div class="numB">600</div>

  $(function(){
    var ln = Number($('.numB').text());
    var $el = $('.numB');
    $($el).animate({ val: ln }, {
      duration: 2000,
      step: function () {
        var num = numComma(Math.floor(this.val));
        // $el.text(num); //have Comma
        $el.text(Math.floor(this.val)); //none Comma
      },
      complete: function () {
        var num = numComma(Math.floor(this.val));
        $el.text(Math.floor(this.val));
      }
    });

    function numComma(x) {
      return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to include the `.each()` function. Then it works just fine.

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".numB").each(function() {
    var ln = Number($(this).text());
    var $el = $(this);
    $($el).animate({
      val: ln
    }, {
      duration: 2000,
      step: function() {
        var num = numComma(Math.floor(this.val));
        // $el.text(num); //have Comma
        $el.text(Math.floor(this.val)); //none Comma
      },
      complete: function() {
        var num = numComma(Math.floor(this.val));
        $el.text(Math.floor(this.val));
      }
    });
  });

  function numComma(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numB">12345</div>
<div class="numB">600</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I didn't know "each" very well. I need to use it often in the future